# Error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux, libevent

After upgrade ubuntu 16 to 18. I got this error when execute tmux

**tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

and here's result when I execute `ldd $(which tmux)`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9878a000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f5588dfc000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f5588bd2000)
libevent-2.0.so.5 => not found
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f55889b7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f55885c6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5588fff000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> libevent-2.0.so.5 => not found

`libevent-2.0-5` (xenial-updates) was repacked to compat-libevent2-5_2.0.21-1ubuntu18_amd64.deb : No conflicts with the Ubuntu 18.04 "libevent-2.1-6".

`compat-libevent2-5` Provides `/usrlib/libevent-2.0.so.5 -> libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9`

Download link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xG1a3GMZuLc1HIRYMP2vythuqjODmN8o/view?usp=sharing

Package install: `sudo gdebi Downloads/compat-libevent2-5_2.0.21-1ubuntu18_amd64.deb`